# how to properly resolve jquery conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

I previously had a problem with jquery conflicting with jquery in the index page of a document and the jquery in the following function

```
    (function (window, document) {

...jquery code not necessary and far to long

})(window, document);
```

I have tried resolving Jquery conflict with the following code

```
     var jQuery132 = $.noConflict(true);
    (function (window, document) {

    .....

})(jQuery132)(window, document);
```

however this doesn't work for resolving the conflict and the function fails.I think it has something to do with the following part

```
})(jQuery132)(window, document);
```

How do use jquery noConflict with this type of function?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this:

```
jQuery.noConflict();

(function (window, document, $) {

   ...

})(window, document, jQuery);
```

With `jQuery` being passed as a parameter to the IIFE. This effectively lets you use the `$` or anything else really ( if you want to use jQuery123 go ahead ) without conflicting inside of the closure generated by the IIFE.